# Phonegap windows phone 8 not keeping session

Tags: session, cordova, windows-phone-8

I've developed an application for `Android`  using `Phonegap`. And the application is working perfectly. I'e used jQuery Mobile to design the interface.

When i tried to build the app for **Windows Phone 8**, I got stuck on an issue.

My app uses web service written in **`PHP`** to fetch data from server. The app has to call two **API** one after another. First one to authenticate the app(something like a `login`) and once authenticated, an API to fetch some data from server.

It seems the phone is not keeping session. The authentication API returns `login success`. The `get app data api` called right after that but it returns 'application is not authenticated'.

the APIs works fine when tested on browser and android device. Please help.

Any kind of help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks in advace :)

Answer (score 1):

the session is expired when i have come back from the payment gateway in windows 8 mobile, that's stopping me to call remaining url's..Iam getting session expired, any one suggests how to maintain session even after the app is closed.This is working for android,iphone,blackberry.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem, just using phonegap with windows phone 8, not jquery mobile.
I login, but the next request says that the session is expired.
Exactly the same code works fine with phonegap on iOS and Android

Comment: have you got any solution for this issue? im still facing this. Please help

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like cookies can be passed between the app and server ([Cordova bug here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2060?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel)) and cookies are necessary to maintain a session between a server and client (so the server knows who the client is).